# How to include HTML5WebView in android project

Tags: java, android, android-activity, apk

I am trying to use HTML5WebView to fix the HTML5 video issue in android. I am not sure how to include the files in the project. Does anyone have any ideas how to go about doing this.

Here is a link to HTML5WebView:
https://code.google.com/p/html5webview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to use the .apk which might be thought as a demo for installation on a real device, but in this case you don't have to use it.
Just download them and insert them into your project. Now just use them like any custom view.
Save [this file](https://html5webview.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/HTML5WebView/src/org/itri/html5webview/HTML5WebView.java) to your project.

Comment: Forgive me, i'm pretty new at android development, but your suggesting that i just save the HTML5WebView.java in the same folder as my activity java file and use it as a webview?

Comment: That'd be one place to save it. I prefer to use another folder, so that I don't mess up my own code with external code. At least it would work that way.

Comment: Well i have the file in my app, but the HTML5WebView.java is throwing "cannot be resolved or is not a field" errors, i'm not sure how to resolve those.

Comment: Of course you also need to add the resource files https://code.google.com/p/html5webview/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FHTML5WebView%2Fres%2Flayout to your project. Just download them and put them into the appropriate folders.

Comment: Awesome, that took care of all of the errors after i found all the files i needed. Now i just need to figure out how to make the activity file i already have work with the HTML5WebView code. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: That HTML5WebView extends a normal WebView, so you can just use it in your layout. It's under 'Custom & Library Views' in Eclipse and you can just use the full name in xml if you do it by hand.